# Oracle hierarchy query throws Not enough memory for connect by operation

Tags: oracle

My following Oracle query fails with "Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation"

QUERY;

```
select u.* 
  from USER u 
          JOIN USER_ROLE ur 
           on ur.USER_ID=u.USER_ID 
 where ur.ROLE_ID=1 
   and u.USER_ID IN (select d.USER_ID 
                       FROM USER d start with d.PARENT_ID=2 
                    connect by d.PARENT_ID=d.USER_ID);
```

How to get this query successfull?

Comment: Most likely you are running on a infinite loop, therefore your memory issue. You have to explain your tables structure and what are you trying to get from then so we can understand the **problem**

Comment: your sub-query is missing PRIOR. Try  `connect by d.PARENT_ID =  prior d.USER_ID`

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to find out?